# mysql fetch all row based on join query and latest date time

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Hello I have two tables:

table1 - `eod_stock`

> company_code | open | high | low | ltp | close | ycp | total_volume | total_value | datetime

table 2 - `company`

> ID | code | name

here `company code = code` so to get all name and other info i used this code:

but first one gives me error and 2nd one returns only one row, but i need all 200 companies with their associated info.

```
select
  company.code,
  company.name,
  eod_stock.open,
  eod_stock.high,
  max(eod_stock.datetime)
from 
  company
  right join company on company.code= eod_stock.company_code;
```

and

```
select
  eod_stock.company_code,
  max(eod_stock.close),
  eod_stock.total_volume,
  eod_stock.total_trade,
  eod_stock.high,
  eod_stock.low,
  eod_stock.ltp,
  max(eod_stock.datetime),
  company.name 
from
  eod_stock 
  inner join company on (company.code = eod_stock.company_code);
```

but first one gives me error and 2nd one returns only one row, but i need all 200 companies with their associated info.

Comment: What error? I see `company` twice in the `FROM` clause, but no `eod_stock`. Assume you mean the second one to be `eod_stock`.

Comment: Can you post a data sample from each table, preferably setup a demo at http://sqlfiddle.com.  The reason you're getting only one row back is the `MAX()` aggregate with no `GROUP BY` (and MySQL allowing you to do that where MSSQL or Oracle would error)

Comment: You use a max() function but no group by it results in one row...

Comment: Michael ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'company'
 this is the error i am getting on first query and for secnd query i just got only one row not all

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to start with a list of the max `datetime` for each `company_code`, which you can do with this basic query:

```
SELECT company_code, MAX(datetime) AS maxdatetime
FROM eod_stock
GROUP BY company_code
```

Join this to a query that gets company code, company name, and end-of-day values, and you should be all set:

```
SELECT
  company.code,
  company.name,
  eod_stock.open,
  eod_stock.high
FROM eod_stock
INNER JOIN company ON company.code = eod_stock.company_code
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT company_code, MAX(datetime) AS maxdatetime
    FROM eod_stock
    GROUP BY company_code) maxdt
  ON maxdt.company_code = eod_stock.company_code AND
     maxdt.maxdatetime = eod_stock.datetime
```

Comment: this gives me this error... ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM eod_stock
INNER JOIN company ON company.code = eod_stock.company_code
INNER' at line 6

Comment: Sorry about that - it was the comma after `eod_stock.high` and right before the `FROM`. I've corrected the query in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error i guess that your have to write :

```
Table2 right join Table1
```

instead of company right join company

the 2nd one to get all company your full join !!

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  eod_stock.company_code,
  max(eod_stock.close),
  eod_stock.total_volume,
  eod_stock.total_trade,
  eod_stock.high,
  eod_stock.low,
  eod_stock.ltp,
  max(eod_stock.datetime),
  company.name 
from
  eod_stock 
 inner join company on (company.code = eod_stock.company_code) group by eod_stock.company_code;
```

dagfr was correct all i needed to add group by in the query.